# Custom excerpt for child template on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been creating a child Wordrpess theme. The parent theme is TwentyTwelve theme.

I override styles.css file and it works perfectly. But I can't replace the_excerpt function on my functions.php

I've been searching but I can't find the solution.

**functions.php**

```
<?php

function custom_excerpt($text) {
    return "Test";
}

function my_child_theme_setup() {
    add_filter('the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt');
    add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt');
    add_filter('default_excerpt', 'custom_excerpt');
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );

?>
```

I just wan't to show the featured image on the excerpt linking the original post.

Thanks!

Comment: I get it! I was filtering the wrong function. The function I have to apply the filter is the_content. But it not differenciate when is the summary and when is the full content. I will add more information if I found a better solution.

Comment: I' solved it this thime using the function is_front_page().